# Visual Studio 2010 "No Target Framework"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I have a big problem with my Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  I installed it but in my Project preferences I cannot choose a Framework Target. It's just empty, even though I installed .NET 4 Full....

Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of project are you creating? When you create a NEW project, what choices do you have at in that dialogue?

Comment: I want to create a new ASP.NET Web Application! It creates the new project, but if a go to the project proferences theres nor Target Framework available!

Comment: If i create a new WPF Application, then i have all my installed Frameworks under the project preferences...Everythings fine except ASP.NET Web Application