# Target framework dropdown empty

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have VS.NET 2010 Premium installed, but there seems to be an issue when trying to target existing .NET frameworks. When I open properties for a web application project, the only option I get is to install a framework. If I open properties for any other project type I get the full list.

So far I've done the following to no avail:

- Repaired and re-installed Microsoft.NET Framework 4 Client Profile
- Repaired and re-installed Microsoft.NET Framework 4 Extended
- Repaired and re-installed Microsoft.NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Repaired and re-installed VS.NET 2010 Premium
- Reapplied and re-installed VS.NET 2010 SP1.

I did find one question on that appear to be related related, but there were no answers unfortunately.

[Visual Studio 2010 "No Target Framework"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430943/visual-studio-2010-no-target-framework)

Any ideas?

Comment: @Verify .net framework is in you system. .Net 4.0 Client framework

Comment: As I mentioned above, it's working for other project types just not web application projects

Comment: : Try to change import export setting from VS2010 Tools option. Select for Web development

Comment: @sarooptrivedi unfortunately it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Try this link hopefully it's helpful otherwise do more research on solving bug.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078164/dotnet-framework-4-missing-from-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this issue as well across a number of different machines and have had to rediscover the answer each time!

The solution that has worked consistently for me is to change the Environment variables on the machine for the User Variables "TEMP" and "TMP".  I repoint both of these variables to "c:\Temp" rather than the default location which includes your user name (with apostrophe) in the path.

[image]

After struggling through each Visual Studio setting related to account specific paths (Projects, Templates, etc.) this has been the only change I have needed to make to fix the problem.

Matt O'Brien

Comment: It did indeed turn out to be an apostrophe causing the problem. A few days ago I got my username renamed and my user profile recreated. After doing that everything worked fine.

Comment: Timing is everything.  I got a new machine last week and couldn't afford a rename scenario so I was able to resolve the issue on my existing profile.  Having said that, I would not recommend user accounts with an apostrophe in it!

Comment: your solution Worked perfect