# No Frameworks in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, frameworks

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional RC, but when I go to create a new project, no frameworks are selectable for the project.

[image]

I have tried the following and restarted after each change:

1. Changed Environment Variables for TEMP and TMP to C:\Temp based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098601/target-framework-dropdown-empty)
2. Ran a repair install on .NET 4.6
3. Uninstalled then reinstalled Visual Studio 2015

Nothing has worked.  I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Does it work in an experimental instance? `devenv.exe /RootSuffix Exp`

Comment: @JohnKoerner Just tried - does the same thing.

Comment: I am also facing same problem in VS 2015 Community edition after I uninstalled 2013 and installed 2015 ... vs2013 worked fine... I couldn't solve issue with existing available solutions ...

Comment: @user1844933 Try and repair Visual Studio, and check whether it has same issue.

In Control Panel, on the Programs and Features page, choose the product edition that you want to repair, and then choose Uninstall/Change.

In the Setup wizard, choose Repair, choose Next, and then follow the remaining instructions. Hopefully that may help you...

Comment: @Zaggler I repaired , reinstalled no use yet..  is anything pending to try before format ?

Answer (score 5):

> I installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional RC

You didn't.  Note the text visible in the screen shot, the words "Shell (Integrated)" are highly relevant.  The shell version of VS is meant for anybody that want to takes advantage of the IDE for their own product but doesn't need the Microsoft-provided languages.  There are two versions of it, the plain shell just provides the GUI, the "integrated" edition adds support for debugging and source control.  A company that creates their own language would take advantage of it.  [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb129445.aspx) describes it well, I'll just quote the introduction:

> The Visual Studio integrated shell includes the integrated development environment (IDE), debugger, and source control integration. **No programming language is included**. However, the integrated shell does provide a framework that allows you to add programming languages

Not so sure how this went wrong, a very rough guess is that you're trying to avoid paying the license fee for the Professional edition.  Use the [Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) instead.